# Using transparent pauses in lstlisting using XeLaTex (beamer)

Tags: xetex, pdftex, listings, pause, transparent

I want to show a piece of code line by line, with lines to be uncovered transparent. The following `tex` code works just fine as long as I compile with `pdflatex`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}

\setbeamercovered{transparent=5}

\lstset{
    language=python,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    numbers=left,
    escapeinside=||
}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{lstlisting}
a = 5         |\pause|
b = a         |\pause|
print(a)      |\pause|
print(b)
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

However it does not work using `xelatex`, which I need for other purposes : every line is visible on every slide. I'd like to mention that switching `\setbeamercovered{transparent=5}` to `\setbeamercovered{invisible}` works as expected both with `pdflatex` and `xelatex`.

Do you know of any conflict between `lstlisting`, `xelatex`, and transparent transitions ? Any workaround ?

Comment: A workaround is to use `lualatex` (unless XeTeX-only features are required)

Comment: This works indeed, thanks !